# iTextSharp - not all characters present in Helvetica font

Tags: fonts, itext

I have some text that contains the Omega character (0x3A9), and when I display this character in the default Helvetica font, nothing appears in the PDF.

I am creating my fonts using

```
BaseFont Helvetica = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
```

and, as expected, Helvetica.CharExists(0x3A9) returns false.

I've also called CharExists(0x3A9) for the TIMES_ROMAN, SYMBOL, and ZAPF_DINGBATS fonts.  All return false.

1. Am I creating the font incorrectly?  Is there a better way to create the font that would include the omega character?
2. Is there a generic way to handle missing characters like this?  Should I just enumerate over all the available fonts until I find one where CharExists(0x3A9) returns true?

My document is in English but has a smattering of special characters - plus/minus, left-and-right double quotes, micron, etc.

p.s. I see that I can create an Arial Font:

```
BaseFont arial = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

and that does contain a glyph for character 0x3A9.  But apparently I can't create the HELVETICA font with the IDENTITY_H encoding.

Comment: HELVETICA, TIMES_ROMAN, SYMBOL, and ZAPF_DINGBATS are standard 14 fonts which each pdf viewer has to provide with a certain, limited character set. If you need more characters, you have to provide a font yourself like you do for Arial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up with is kind of complicated, but seems solid.  Each time I go to add text to my document, which up until now I had done by simply creating a new Phrase, I first enumerate each character in the string and call BaseFont.CharExists().  If the answer is false for any character, I split the text into chunks based on continuous sequences of CharExists() being true or false.  Then, for the chunks that exist in Helvetica I create a Chunk in Helvetica, and the others I create a Chunk in Arial, and assemble those Chunks into my Phrase.

The reason I do this (which is probably obvious to most readers, but just in case) is that I don't want to always add the Arial font to my PDF files (to keep the size down), and 95% of my documents don't contain characters like Omega that would require Arial.  This way, I only add the Arial font to those few documents that actually need it.

```
Phrase phrase = null;
string s = "";
for (int i = 0 ; i < text.Length ; i++)
{
   char c = text[i];
   if (fonts.Regular.BaseFont.CharExists(c))
      s += c;   // Accumulate Helvetica characters in 's'
   else
   {
      // Try adding the Arial font
      iTextSharp.text.Font arial = fonts.Arial;       // Creates the Arial font and adds it to the document if not already there
      if (arial == null)
      {
         Debug.WriteLine("   Arial font not found");
         s += c;
      }
      else if (!arial.BaseFont.CharExists(c))
      {
         Debug.WriteLine("   Arial does not contain the required glyph");
         s += c;
      }
      else
      {
         // We have a character that Helvetica doesn't have, that Arial does
         if (phrase == null)
         {
            // This is the first time we've realize that we need a split phrase
            if (s.Length > 0)
            {
               // There was Helvetica text before the Arial character.
               phrase = new Phrase(s, fonts.Regular);
               // This code assumes that non-Helvetica characters generally come singly
               phrase.Add(new Chunk(c, arial));
               s = "";
            }
            else
            {
               // The Arial character is the first one in the string
               phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(c, arial));
            }
         }
         else
         {
            // This is not the first Arial character in the string
            if (s != "")
            {
               // There were Helvetica characters before this Arial character
               phrase.Add(new Chunk(s, fonts.Regular);
               s = "";
            }
            phrase.Add(new Chunk(c, arial));
         }
      }
   }
}

if (phrase == null)
{
   // We did not encounter any Arial characters, create a simple Phrase
   phrase = new Phrase(text, fonts.Regular);
}
else if (s.Length > 0)
{
   // There were Helvetica characters at the end of the string, add them now
   phrase.Add(new Chunk(s, fonts.Regular));
}
```